# React Native Selecting Item in array

Tags: arrays, list, react-native

I have the following data in the array

```
let mydata = [ { name: 'Mickey', color: 'Blue'}, { name:'Donald' , color: 'Yellow'}, { name: 'Goofy', color : 'Red'}]
```

I would like to add item in between and display some items. So I created the following

```
let tmpdata = []; 
let newdata = [{ name:'Daisy', color:'Pink'}]; 

for (let i=0;i< mydata.length;i++) {
   if (i==1) {
     tmpdata = [...tmpdata, ...newdata];
     tmpdata = [...tmpdata, ...mydata[i]];
   } else {
      tmpdata = [...tmpdata, ...mydata[i]];
   }  
}
mydata = tmpdata;
console.log(mydata[1].name);
```

Any idea how to do that ? Can I use mydata[i] ? I am pretty new. In .Net and others, I can do that.

Comment: Do you just need to add newdata at mydata[1]?

Comment: I need to add to mydata in between the list and then display any selected data. Example, I need to put the data in between Mickey and Donald.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the splice() method to add items at any index in the array.

As per the example you shared, here's what you can do:

```
let mydata = [
  { name: "Mickey", color: "Blue" },
  { name: "Donald", color: "Yellow" },
  { name: "Goofy", color: "Red" },
];

let newdata = [{ name: "Daisy", color: "Pink" }]; 

mydata.splice(1, 0, newdata[0]);

console.log(mydata[1].name)
```

[Splice method doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Awesome. If it worked, please accept my answer so that others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your idea. It solved my problem

Comment: please don't post comments inside answers. Let's keep the answer section clean. Thanks